# Unresolved external symbol - show which line the symbol is in .c project

Tags: c, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm trying to configure VS correctly to write some simple c programs.

If a function **dummy()** is not found, the function name is not highlight in the code, there is only a build error:

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol **dummy** referenced in function main
Line: 1

Is there a way to make VS intellisense work for function names with .c files?
Why compiler doesn't show the error line number (*Line: 1* is not very helpful)?

Sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void dummy()
{
}

int main()
{
    dummyX(); //dummyX, dummy typo. Results in "unresolved external..." error

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Unresolved symbols are found on linking stage, when there is no more line numbers involved, as the linker is working with object files rather than sources.

Comment: @EugeneSh. right. But VS shouldn't be able to find out that the function name is wrong before compiling? Just like C# projects.

Comment: C# and C are *very* different beasts.

Comment: So I need to ctrl+f the unresolved external symbol name to find which line it is? This could be somehow automated by VS.

Comment: If the underlying compiler/linker is not providing this information - where would VS get it from?

Comment: Is `dummy` a real function or are you looking to find if something is misspelled?  If the latter, you should get a compiler warning for an implicit declaration.

Comment: Please make a [mre].

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, C and C# are very different beasts; but if I'm not mistaken the debug information in object files compiled with the relevant flags is not far behind the information in .net assemblies; for this question relevant: ["DWARF encodes a full mapping between lines in the C source code and machine code addresses."](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information) So the argument about object files and missing line numbers is not true for files with debug information. I think VC's pdb files carry even more information.

Comment: In C89, there are implicit rules for defining functions that prevent this from being flagged a warning in some compilers. If you have the choice, try using C99, and turn up the warning level.

Comment: @Yunnosch sample included.

Comment: Hard to get wrong, C4031 is a level 1 warning.  It is a warning however, so if you only look at errors then you'd miss it.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > General, "Treat Warnings as Errors" = Yes.

Comment: @HansPassant, oh, there it is in the hidden warnings! Thank you SO legend.

Comment: Hi Pedro77, do you get your answer during the discussion? If your issue still persists, please feel free to let us know.